# Use all 5.1 speakers with a Stereo Source / No speaker fill

Tags: windows-7, audio, drivers, speakers

I've been reading up on how to make for ex. Youtube play sound to all my speakers. I have 5.1 Setup from Samsung which connects with an optical cable to my onboard Realtek soundcard. Latest drivers did not produce a speaker fill option in the sound proprieties.
Please give me some ideas on how to play Youtube on at least 4 of the 5 speakers with the same power.

Here are my options:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vrsq7.jpg]

Difference between 5.1 and Stereo is that 5.1 is quieter although the TEST only produces Stereo even if 5.1 is selected

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

Get the 'proper' drivers directly from [Reatek](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) which will give you all the options back, including a full 5/7.1 setup page with customisable delays & EQ.

[image]

Comment: I don't have any speaker configuration due to the fact that i connect with an optical cable..because i did install the latest drivers

http://i.imgur.com/Nzy0zL4.jpg

I cannot paste the image directly for some reason...

Comment: ahhh...I've never tried it over optical - on my setup I actually only ever take stereo over optical. As 5.1 over 2-channel optical is a compressed format, it's best to decode only once, at the far end, not in the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue, and I tried **many** driver versions from Realtek website, but none of them worked.

the only solution was to use [Driver Pack](https://drp.su/en).

then, I got a working driver with "Speaker Fill" option.

Notice - DRP installs few additional software (Anti virus, Notifier, etc). just make sure to uncheck whatever software you don't want to install.